# scipy.optimize.minimize Nelder-Mead 'fatol' does nothing, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, minimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am running Nelder-Mead optimization on a fitness function. The function returns a mean squared error (MSE) of the difference between two arrays.

I want the optimization to stop when the MSE is below a specified value.

My optimization setup is as follows:

```
options = {'maxiter': 100, 'disp': False, 'initial_simplex': init_simplex_arr, 'fatol': 0.001}

result = minimize(fitness_function, x0, method='Nelder-Mead', bounds=bounds, options=options)
```

The fitness function is summarized below:

```
def fitness_function(x):

  # Arrays
  ref_array = load_ref_arr("folder/reference_array.txt"
  calc_array = calc_new_array(x)

  # Calculate MSE
  mse = np.mean((ref_array-calc_array)**2)
  return mse
```

Sample outputs of the fitness_function:

```
0.0010713476460687801
0.0002628635483247014
0.0009798654399516093
0.00024260671159317867
0.00099163708787692
0.00017078416043779879
0.0010094022276385295
0.00023695061737201775
0.0005606370238849049
0.00019916645596727386
0.0004211745861734694
0.00020850874852816853
0.0004442950360513234
0.0001982226314876404
0.00038448272667955606
0.00018130359654993492
0.000321567089210017
0.00015139776932472033
0.0002222159416127054
0.0003240715869791624
0.00015971480682450465
0.00031676015901488597
0.00016306956422549413
0.0003316191108649874
0.00015673514985682063
0.0001818140712213015
0.00021525980930940775
0.00015543062242850684
0.00024112123987462002
0.00015026391998004834
0.0002119574083483072
0.00015300530091189144
0.0002051062480492777
0.0001415150195302095
0.00021263582928948626
0.00014027617152343477
0.000178745382624011
```

To my understanding, with fatol=0.001 the optimization should terminate and not continue if the difference between f(n) and f(n-1) is less than 0.001. For example see output 2 and 3 in the list:

```
abs(0.0002628635483247014 - 0.0009798654399516093) = 0.0007169 < 0.001
```

It continues to run, I want it to stop.

Any help on this behaviour would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
 while (fcalls[0] < maxfun and iterations < maxiter):
    if (numpy.max(numpy.ravel(numpy.abs(sim[1:] - sim[0]))) <= xatol and
            numpy.max(numpy.abs(fsim[0] - fsim[1:])) <= fatol):
        break
```

This code extracted from https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/c0dc7fccc53d8a8569cde5d55673fca284bca191/scipy/optimize/optimize.py for minimize Nelder Mead shows that the stop condition based in fatol is in one logic and with an expression using xatol. So it is good to investigate xatol along with fatol. This might explain why the covergence didnt stop while just fatol requirement is reached.